# npm start gets 401 and node app.js gets 200 response

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, fetch-api, http-status-code-401

I have a React project that I run with npm start and this code gets 401 Error from the second fetch (the first one is ok). It runs fine returning 200 only with node, like in "node App.js".

So what would I need to do to run my React project getting 200 response? Why is there this difference between npm and node to this request response?

```
const clientID = <ClientID>
const clientSecret = <ClientSecret>
const encode = Buffer.from(`${clientID}:${clientSecret}`, 'utf8').toString('base64')

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${encode}`,
            },
};

fetch("https://auth-nato.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials", requestOptions)
.then(response => { return response.json() })
.then(data => { 
  const requestOptions2 = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${data.access_token}`
            },
    body: '{"username":"Ana", "password":"test123","user_id":"ana@email.com"}'
  };
  fetch('https://j1r07lanr6.execute-api.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/register', requestOptions2)
  .then(response => {console.log(response)});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was a CORS issue that needed to be set correctly on the back-end. My workaround was disabling chrome web security and removing "mode: no-cors".
I've tried adding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://localhost:3000" to headers but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) - is not presented in the browser's javascript.

Instead of

```
const encode = Buffer.from(`${clientID}:${clientSecret}`, 'utf8').toString('base64')
```

use just

```
const encode = btoa(`${clientID}:${clientSecret}`);
```

Read more about base64 encoding on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64).